# How to use facebook Login in react native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to use facebook login in my react native app.. i used firebase on web (reactJs ).. now i use same method for react native app but its not working...

i want fbSignin button which allow me to use user profile pic and name etc..

here is my code..

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Container, Item, Button, Text } from "native-base"
import * as firebase from "firebase"
import { FBLogin, FBLoginManager } from "react-native-facebook-login"

// Initialize Firebase

var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAK7dr25d-qnsHCdvkeoVPWs7Q0",

  authDomain: "quiz-appasdn-ba8c1.firebaseapp.com",

  databaseURL: "httpsasdasdasdasd-ba8c1.firebaseio.com",

  projectId: "quiz-asdaasdasdc1",

  storageBucket: "pplicationasdasd-asddappspot.com",

  messagingSenderId: "23764257465237"

};

firebase.initializeApp(config);



var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();


class App extends Component {

  fbLogin() {

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {

      var token = result.credential.accessToken;

      var user = result.user;

    }).catch(function (error) {

      var errorCode = error.code;

      var errorMessage = error.message;

      var email = error.email;

      var credential = error.credential;

    });

  }



  render() {

    return (

      <Button onPress={this.fbLogin.bind(this)}>

        <Text>faacebook Login</Text>

      </Button>
    );
  }
};
```

export default App

thanks in advance..

Comment: Please remove the API key from the post

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` doesn't work for react-native you have to use `firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)` along with the `react-native-fbsdk` to sign in with facebook..
here is the snippet

```
     <LoginButton
       onLoginFinished={
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            alert("login has error: " + result.error);
          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            alert("login is cancelled.");
          } else {
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
              (data) => {
                const provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
                const credential = provider.credential(data.accessToken.toString());
                firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
                .then(function(userCredential) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(userCredential));
                });
              }
            )
          }
        }
      }
      onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
```

Resources :
[Facebook React Native SDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#3-configure-native-projects/)
[Firebase signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential)

Answer (score 0):

i just know lib react native to use login facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login mybe this can help you :)